# Does fixed step size and fixed mini-batch size lead to the global minimizer of least square in $L_2$ stochastic sense?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f(x)=||Ax-b||_2^2$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times n}$ where $n \leq N$ and a $A$ is a full column rank. Consider minimizing $f$ as follows:

$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} ||Ax-b||_2^2\tag{1}.
$$

The objective function in Problem (1) is a strongly convex function and has a unique solution, i.e., $x^*=(A^{\top}A)^{-1}A^{\top}b$. Now suppose we apply the stochastic mini-batch gradient descent as the following:
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k -\gamma \Big(\frac{2}{|B|}\big((A_{B\bullet})^{\top}(A_{B\bullet}^{\top}x-b_{B}\big)\Big)
$$
where $A_{B\bullet}$ is the restriction of matrix $A$ to rows whose indices are in $B \subseteq \{1, \dots,N\}$ (a matrix that contains some rows of $A$), and $b_{B}$ contains elements of vector $b$ whose indices are in $B$, $\gamma$ is a fixed step-length (learning rate), and mini-batch size ($|B|$) is fixed and does not increase. Note that, $\frac{2}{|B|}\big((A_{B\bullet})^{\top}(A_{B\bullet}^{\top}x-b_{B}\big)$ is the stochastic mini-batch gradient.

**Question:**

Is is possible to show the random sequence $(x_k)$ converges to $x*$ in stochastic $L_2$ sense as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x_k}[||x_k-x^*||^2_2] \to 0 \text{ as } k \to \infty?
$$

I have been searching optimization literature and could not a find paper that shows the above under the following conditions:

1. $\gamma$ is a fixed step length and does not decrease as $k$ increases.
2. The mini-batch size is fixed and does not increase as $k$ increases.

I appreciate if you help me to find papers that show what I am looking for.

Comment: I think conditioned on the training data, xk convergences in law to a Gaussian centered at least squares estimator, with covariance proportional to identity times stepsize.

Comment: You might want to read this blogpost (and references there in) https://francisbach.com/rethinking-sgd-noise/, and then post an answer to your question.

Comment: Alternatively, read these slides http://cbl.eng.cam.ac.uk/pub/Intranet/MLG/ReadingGroup/sgd.pdf.

Comment: @dohmatob: thank you so much. They are very helpful. I will get back if I come up with more questions.